# Syntax.Analysis of the sentence

Tags: phrase-meaning, parsing

> She didn’t want to hear that this was the platform he usually sat on to wait for the cheaper train, she didn’t want to become part of his ri-diculous pattern **of commuting from this new home to get audiences and hearings and to advance his documents**.

The whole structure of this sentence is quite clear to me except for the function of the highlighted portion.

Is "*of commuting from this new home*" attribute of the word "pattern"?

Is "*to get audiences and hearings*" object?

Comment: Yes: the _of_ PP is complement (as opposed to modifier) of "pattern". But the infinitival clause is not object, but adjunct of purpose (note that "in order" could be inserted: _commuting from this new home in order to get audiences and hearings and to advance his documents_.

Comment: so,  ' to wait for' is also adjunct of purpose, isnt it?

Comment: Yes: "to wait for the cheaper train" is also an adjunct of purpose.